# How do I mock asyncio database context managers?

Tags: python-3.x, database, mocking, python-asyncio

I've been struggling for a bit to mock the typical async database connection setup:

```py
async with aiomysql.create_pool(...) as pool:
    async with pool.acquire() as connection:
        async with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            await cursor.execute("BEGIN")
            ...
```

My first try for a test function looked about like this:

```py
async def test_database(mocker: pytest_mock.MockerFixture):
    context = mocker.AsyncMock()
    pool = mocker.AsyncMock()
    connection = mocker.AsyncMock()
    cursor = mocker.AsyncMock()
    cursor.fetchall.return_value = [{'Database': 'information_schema'}]
    cursor.fetchone.return_value = {'COUNT(*)': 0}
    cursor.rowcount = 0
    connection.cursor.return_value.__aenter__.return_value = cursor
    pool.acquire.return_value.__aenter__.return_value = connection
    context.__aenter__.return_value = pool
    mocker.patch('aiomysql.create_pool', return_value=context)

    async with aiomysql.create_pool() as p:
        async with p.acquire() as c:
            async with c.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute("BEGIN")
```

If you've been getting `AttributeError`s for missing `__aenter__`s, this post is for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part to note is that there is no `await` between the `async with` and function call since `create_pool`, `acquire`, and `cursor` are synchronous. The test function above will produce new `AsyncMock` objects that require an await on `acquire()` etc. to return the next prepared `AsyncMock`. Instead we want `acquire()` etc. to return immediately. The solution is to mix `Mock`/`MagicMock` and `AsyncMock`.

```py
async def test_database(mocker: pytest_mock.MockerFixture):
    context = mocker.AsyncMock()
    pool = mocker.Mock()
    connection = mocker.Mock()
    cursor = mocker.AsyncMock()
    cursor.fetchall.return_value = [{'Database': 'information_schema'}]
    cursor.fetchone.return_value = {'COUNT(*)': 0}
    cursor.rowcount = 0
    connection.cursor.return_value = mocker.AsyncMock()
    connection.cursor.return_value.__aenter__.return_value = cursor
    pool.acquire.return_value = mocker.AsyncMock()
    pool.acquire.return_value.__aenter__.return_value = connection
    context.__aenter__.return_value = pool
    mocker.patch('aiomysql.create_pool', return_value=context)

    # calls create_pool synchronously and gets 'context',
    # which is an AsyncMock and facilitates the __aenter__ call,
    # which returns 'pool' as a regular Mock
    async with aiomysql.create_pool() as p:
        # calls 'acquire()' synchronously and gets an anonymous AsyncMock,
        # which facilitates the __aenter__ call,
        # which returns 'connection' as a regular Mock
        async with p.acquire() as c:
            # again, 'cursor()' synchronously, get AsyncMock,
            # __aenter__ to get 'cursor'
            async with c.cursor() as cur:
                # continue regular operations on AsyncMock object
                await cur.execute("BEGIN")
```

Note: `aiomysql` specific: If you want to use `connection.begin()` and the likes, add `connection.begin = mocker.Mock()`, and it'll `__call__` the object synchronously.